# location manager not checking properly

Tags: android, boolean, android-wifi, locationmanager

This is the code i have to check for my current lcoation. I have Wifi turned on my android device but networkIsEnabled is always false.

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
boolean networkIsEnabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
double lat = loc.getLatitude();
double lng = loc.getLongitude();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem.

Your manifest should have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<application ....

   <receiver
          android:name="com.your_package.ConnectionChangeReceiver"
          android:label="NetworkConnection">

          <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
                    <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"/>
                    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
          </intent-filter>

    </receiver>

</application>
```

The block in the application tag isn't necessary if you just want your current location, but if you're looking to actively detect when the network state changes, then you'll need that. In that case, ConnectionChangeReceiver would be your class that extends BroadcastReceiver.

Hopefully this helps.

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify, network refers to 3/4G. If your WIFI is on with airplanemode on, network will be false. You have to check both WIFI AND 3/4G.

```
  ConnectivityManager conMngr =   (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  NetworkInfo wifi = conMngr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI); 
  NetworkInfo mobile = conMngr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

  if(wifi.isAvailable() && wifi.isConnected())
     // available + connected

  if(mobile.isAvailable() && mobile.isConnected())
     // available + connected
```

Note: in order to check the wifi state like this, you need "ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" in your manifest. I added it above.

**EDIT 2:**

This is how you get LAT/LONG:

**GPSTracker Class:**
http://pastebin.com/ESXzfdcu

**Class you want lag/long in:**

```
 GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

 if(gps.canGetLocation()) {

     double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
     double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    

 }else {
     gps.showSettingsAlert();
 }
```

Instead of displaying the lat/long in a toast, you can simply set some lag/long variables and use them where ever you need.

Comment: it works if i have the gps enabled as well, but without it's still false

Comment: @user3748957 I updated my answer. Hopefully this added info helps.

Comment: that makes sure that i my mobile is connected. any idea on how to get my current lat and lng from this. I updated my code to show how i'm currently doing it.

Comment: Yeah I have a class I use for that. It's too large to paste here though. Hop over to my chatroom: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56653/jonny07

Comment: @user3748957 I added my method of getting current lat/long.

Comment: I am using you class and it works fine when i enable my gps. but if it's just for wifi/3g/4g it's not working

Comment: I've only ever used GPS based lat/long. I'm not sure if you can do it with just WIFI/3G. and IF you can, it would have to be some geolocation stuff. I would just give the user an error to turn on GPS if its off.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't check whether WiFi has been enabled, isProviderEnabled() checks whether the user has enabled Network Provider in the location settings of the phone.

Comment: i want to get my current location based on my wifi/mobile network provider. so how do i do that

Comment: I would recommend you use LocationClient with Fused location provider, there is sufficient documentation provided by google on how to make your application location aware.
on the other hand, use location manager to check if both Network Provider and GPS providers have been turned off. If so, direct the user to the location source settings using an intent to turn on the location services.